# Linkedin Open Graph Sharing not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a page setup for Open Graph Protocol because our app is built upon Angular 1.x now when we share a URL using LinkedIn. Share Popup opens but it does not crawl open graph tags sometimes and sometimes it shows the proper crawl tags it was working fine till last week. here is the image which shows the preview area:
[image: Linkedin Share Preview]

Scenario for sharing a link:

1. User comes on our site: `www.example.com/event/[EVENT_ID]` and clicks share to LinkedIn.
2. Popups opens using: `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://example.com/event/0u83s43rf6r/4295028179` where `4295028179` is event id and `0u83s43rf6r` is a random key for sharing because of cache busting.
3. Now we are using apache `mod_rewrite` to redirect LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter bot to our crawler page where Open graph tags are rendered.

Apache Mod Rewrite Settings in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(facebookexternalhit/(.*)|Facebot|Twitter(.*)|Pinterest|LinkedIn(.*)|LinkedInBot)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(event)/([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$  https://share.example.com/web/crawler/details/$3 [R=301,L]
```

So the end url becomes when crawler redirect based on `USER AGENT` where open graph tags are rendered: `http://share.example.com/web/crwaler/details/4295028179`

Here is the rendered html tags:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.location = 'https://example.com/event/236129271' // if it's a browser then redirect it to website</script>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Event Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Event Description" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="Event Thumbnail" />
  <meta name="title" content="LinkedIn Share Test" />
  <meta name="description" content="Event Description" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="188" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="71" />
  <!-- Twitter Card Working Fine-->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Event Title">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Event Description">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="Event Image">
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Last week this logic is working fine on Linkedin but now somehow it's not working.

Comment: I've never gotten OG attributes to work on linkedin.  I think they only parse tags from popular sites.  You can copy the source of another page, paste it on your own server as raw HTML, and they will not parse the tags.  There is nothing wrong with your tags, it's 100% LI support issue.

Comment: Try tailing your access log files or grepping for Linked (the crawler UA), you will probably see that LI is not even scraping your site.

Comment: I've already check the access logs and Linkedin bot is coming but it's not showing the accurate preview in the popup.

Comment: it's possible that your image is too small.   80x150 is the reported minimum according to: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, you have the right `og:` tags, etc..

Whenever you're not sure that you're using the LinkedIn share API, check out your website with the [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/), and this will tell you how the LinkedIn API is looking at your webpage.  It covers many things, from `<title>` tags, to `og:` tags, to `oEmbed` tags, etc., etc..

Worried about caching?  Why not test a URL like `example.com?someFakeParameter=123`?  This will similarly bypass the caching at the LinkedIn Post Inspector.

If you could post your actual URL that you're sharing, I could give you a better answer, but hopefully something here helps!

Comment: This caching has been driving me crazy. I had removed the element it was taking the title from and it was still showing up.