# OpenGraph Links not displaying on Linkedin (but does display on facebook)

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

The Opengraph tagging on [a site I develop][1] is setup as well as I can tell. Works fine on facebook but 'can't be displayed on linkedin'.

Having done my research I'm aware of the caching period and different ways to deliver opengraph. Can anyone shed light on what I'm missing?

Have tried two separate implementations:

A script based implementation

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https:https://www.tssimmigration.com.au/news/single/skilled-190-visa-pathway-for-stem-graduates"
  },
  "headline": "Skilled 190 Visa pathway for STEM graduates",
  "image": [
    "https://www.tssimmigration.com.au/images/uploads/home/171215_DM_TSS_384_1.jpg"
   ],
  "datePublished": "19 JAN 2018",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Micaela Hoglund"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "TSS Immigration",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://www.tssimmigration.com.au/img/tss.immi3.png"
    }
  },
  "description": "<p>Just one of the range of immigration pathways open to those skilled in a STEM profession is the Skilled Nominated (Subclass 190) Visa.</p>"
}
</script>
```

And a Meta Tagging implementation

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
            <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.tssimmigration.com.au/images/uploads/home/hero6_copy.jpg" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.tssimmigration.com.au/" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="Australian Migration Agents & Consultants in Melbourne | TSS Immigration" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="TSS Immigration are registered migration agents based in Melbourne. Our Expert Migration Agents will evaluate your eligibility and assist you to get an Australian Visa." />
```

Comment: Don't just link to an external site. Post the code that you are having problems with here. Try to narrow down the code to the specific issue as per the guidelines for providing a [mcve]

Comment: @Alan Thanks, Sorry im new to this platform. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the same issue as here [Linkedin Open Graph Sharing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251479/linkedin-open-graph-sharing-not-working)

**I don't know if this is the truth** but the first comment says that "it depends on the site popularity".
If your site is not popular enough, LinkedIn won't display it.

I have the same issue on one of my site, OG works perfectly on facebook but never showing on Linkedin.

Even though I copy/paste an html page from a site where the OG is showing on LinkedIn...